# How to replicate the each observation by different no.of times with a change in one variable in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data set and i want to replicate each observation by no.of times is equal to (termination year - filing year) and then i want to replace the filling year+1 till termination year.

l_c_final

```
id filing_year termination_year
1  1992         1995
2  2005         2009
3  1995         1997
```

Expected output:

```
id  filing_year  termination_year
1   1992         1995
2   1993         1995
3   1994         1995
4   1995         1995
5   2005         2009
6   2006         2009
7   2007         2009
8   2008         2009
9   2009         2009
10  1995         1997
11  1996         1997
12  1997         1997
```

Tried :

```
l_c_fin_curr1 = l_c_final

l_c_fin_curr = l_c_fin_curr1[]
l_c_fin_curr = subset(l_c_fin_curr,filing_year==99999) # creating empty dataframe
for (i in 1:length(l_c_fin_curr1[,1])) {
    cur_yr = l_c_fin_curr1$filing_year[i]
    ter_yr = l_c_fin_curr1$termination_year[i]
    n = as.numeric(ter_yr - cur_yr)
    dim = dim(l_c_fin_curr)[1]
    l_c_fin_curr[(dim+1):(dim+n+1),] = l_c_fin_curr1[i,]
    l_c_fin_curr$filing_year[(dim+1):(dim+n+1)] = l_c_fin_curr$filing_year[(dim+1):(dim+n+1)] + (0:n)
}
```

I got the answer as i assume with the above code but the problem is the size of my dataset is 4 Million records which is taking more than 48 HRS .so I need someone's help on this.

Answer (score 1):

We could replicate the sequence of rows by the difference of columns 3 and 2 to create the 'dfN'.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dfN)`), grouped by 'id', we assign  (`:=`) the 'filing_year' by adding the first observation of 'filing_year' with sequence (`0:(.N-1)`).  Finally, change the 'id' as the sequence of rows.

```
dfN <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), (df1[,3]- df1[,2]+1L)),]
library(data.table)
setDT(dfN)[, filing_year:=filing_year[1L]+0:(.N-1) ,id][, id:= 1:.N]
dfN
#    id filing_year termination_year
# 1:  1        1992             1995
# 2:  2        1993             1995
# 3:  3        1994             1995
# 4:  4        1995             1995
# 5:  5        2005             2009
# 6:  6        2006             2009
# 7:  7        2007             2009
# 8:  8        2008             2009
# 9:  9        2009             2009
#10:  10       1995             1997
#11:  11       1996             1997
#12:  12       1997             1997
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i am using the above code for sample data it is working fine , but when i am using the same code for 4 Million observation i am getting the following error:   Error in rep(seq_len(nrow(l_c_final)), (l_c_final[, 4] - l_c_final[, 2] +  : 
  invalid 'times' argument

Comment: @ashok Can you try it on a smaller subset and check if it still shows the error?  I would recommend to split up the data into chunks and then execute it as 4 million observations when extended based on the difference will be huge.

Comment: i made it into 4 parts ,it works fine for 1st 3 parts(for 1 to 3MIllion),but when i am working with the last chunk (3Million to end) i am getting the same error as above.

Comment: @ashok You can check the tail part of the data to see if there is anything unusual.  Make the last part again cut into smaller chunks to pinpoint the problem.